# Javascript: Regex .test() for whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

Strange regex result when looking for any white space characters

```
new RegExp('^[^\s]+$').test('aaa');
=> true
```

That's expected, but then...

```
new RegExp('^[^\s]+$').test('aaa  ');
=> true
```

How does that return true?

Comment: It's just a typo: In string literals, a backslash is an escape character. Since ``\s`` doesn't mean anything, it's just an `s`. This is why we have regex literals.

Comment: Thanks. Silly mistake. Obvious in hindsight.

Comment: BTW you should probably use \S instead of [^\s]

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape `\` in the string by `\\`. Otherwise, the generated regex would be `/^[^s]+$/`, which matches anything other than a string includes `s`.

```
new RegExp('^[^\\s]+$').test('aaa  ');
```

---

Or you can use `\S` for matching anything other than whitespace.

```
new RegExp('^\\S+$').test('aaa  ');
```

---

It would be better to use regex directly instead of parsing a regex string pattern.

```
/^[^\s]+$/.test('aaa  ');

// or

/^\S+$/.test('aaa  ');
```